# Difference between unmock and dontMock in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

So I've been writing a successful unit test library and all seems well. And then I noticed in some online examples that where I do this:-

`jest.unmock('../lib/q');`

Others do this:-

`jest.dontMock('../lib/q');`

I can't find any documentation on the Jest site (the documentation isn't great let's be honest), so I changed one of my suites for a giggle to `dontMock` and quite a lot exploded ... What's the difference?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is [covered in the Jest documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/troubleshooting.html#i-m-using-babel-and-my-unmocked-imports-aren-t-working).

Seems that we should all use `unmock` now to prevent hoisting of the mocked to above the ES6 import:

> #### I'm using babel and my unmocked imports aren't working?
>
> Upgrade `jest-cli` to `0.9.0`.
>
> **Explanation:**
>
> ```
> jest.dontMock('foo');
>
> import foo from './foo';
> ```
>
> In ES2015, import statements get hoisted before all other
>
> ```
> var foo = require('foo'); jest.dontMock('foo'); // Oops!
> ```
>
> In Jest 0.9.0, a new API `jest.unmock` was introduced. Together with a
>   plugin for babel, this will now work properly when using `babel-jest`:
>
> ```
> jest.unmock('foo'); // Use unmock!
>
> import foo from './foo';
>
> // foo is not mocked!
> ```
>
> See the [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/getting-started.html) guide on how to enable babel support.

Comment: As of just a few hours ago, it seems like the issue with imports being hoisted above `dontMock` has been fixed: https://facebook.github.io/jest/blog/2016/04/12/jest-11.html